# Which Select query will run faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I am trying to get maximum ID from a table which has approx 1 million records.
Please suggest me which on of these query will execute faster.

Option 1:

```
select top 1 SurveyUserResponseID from surveyuserresponse order by SurveyUserResponseID desc
```

Option 2:

```
select max(SurveyUserResponseID) from surveyuserresponse
```

as per actual execution plan both query took same time to execute.

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Answer (score 2):

You can try it by yourself. Run your query with time statistics. Like so:

```
set statistics time on;
select top 1 SurveyUserResponseID from surveyuserresponse order by SurveyUserResponseID desc
set statistics time off;
```

and see on the "messages" tab how long it took to execute each query.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi I am trying to get maximum ID from a table which has approx 1 million records. Please suggest me which on of these query will execute faster.

As per yourself they'll both take the same time:

> both query took same time to execute.

Therefore neither query will be faster than the other.